# Python Launcher not responding with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Python and Pygame, and right now I'm trying to open a test window with some simple code :

```
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')

while True: # main game loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

When I try to run it, I get the welcome message in terminal ("pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html"), and the python launcher starts, but it never opens. The icon simply bounces in the dock for a while, and then says Application Not Responding.

Python Launcher initialized normally with other code that doesn't use pygame, and python, pip and pygame are all up to date. I have also tried to run other pieces of code from tutorials, but everything gets the same result. I installed the new macOS Catalina today, if that makes a difference.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is not any obvious issue in this code.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Could you add a few print statements through the code to see where the code gets to? (e.g after `set_caption`, inside the for loop, before and after `update`) Also interesting information would be platform + python version)

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem with essentially the same code above, and upgrading the pygame library solved the issue, as answered by Tom-cz in a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496097/13407487.

If you run the above code in IDLE or python console, you'll see it cause the Python Launcher to hang (and bounce in the dock) with no window appearing:

```
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
```

The solution was to upgrade pygame:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

My setup:
MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
Python 3.8.1
pygame 1.9.6 -> which I upgraded to 2.0.0.dev6

Comment: This worked for me. I'm running Mojave. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the specific version of pygame.Do this in prompt:

```
pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```