# Pygame 1.9.6 not loading in Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.8

Really strange issue here. I have a 64bit copy of Python 3.8.1 on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.2). I have successfully installed pygame via `pip3 install pygame`. Every time I run Python3 and import pygame, I get the successful message of `hello from the pygame community...`.

However, if I run any program that requires an import of pygame, the icon for my python launcher just loops and loads for an infinite amount of time. I get no error messages. I literally get nothing. No opened windows. Just a blank line on the terminal (and IDLE terminal) window after the `hello from the...` message.

I have on my Mac taskbar a bouncing icon of Python, indicating that it is loading. But nothing happens? I've tested this on every instance of a pygame program with no success. Even the Aliens example embedded within the program does not work.

Comment: this question has been [answered] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Did this in Terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

and in PyCharm I installed pygame package once more into project interpreter with "Specify version" option selected for a specific version: 2.0.0.dev6

Then it started working.

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked for me!! I've been trying to make this work for so long!!